# Why model.addAttribute and ${} is not matching and it shows just . on web?

Tags: spring, jsp, addattribute

I just started to learn `jsp` and `spring`. I deleted `formattedDate` (as a `default`) in `HomeController.java` and changed to `model.addAttribute("answer", "yes")` and on web, it only shows . and i don't understand why.
I tried to put definition like `String answer = "yes"` but it didnt work.

this is *HoneController.java*:

```
    @Controller
    public class HomeController {
        @RequestMapping("/main")
        public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
            model.addAttribute("answer", "yes");

            return "home";
        }
    }
```

and here is *home.jsp*:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@ page session="false" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Home Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>
        hello
    </h1>
    <P> Is it happening? : ${answer}. </P>
    </body>
    </html>
```

There was no error messages
[image: this is the result.]

Comment: Try to add `<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>` at top of your  `home.jsp` and see does it work or not .

Comment: @Swati It's still not working..

Comment: Try to print like this then -> `<c:out value="${answer}"/>`

Comment: @Swati It's the same. Just one dot.

Comment: Your screenshot shows that the path used to display your page is `/second/`. But the controller method you're showing us is mapped to `/main`. So you're not executing this method.